# How to update DOM element with every loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

here i want to update demox element with all iteration of jsoDemo,but i only get final element in array.How do i arrange loop so that i update one by one ?

```
function GETJSON() {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsoDemo.length; i++) {
        var xxx = jsoDemo[i].name;
        console.log(xxx);
    }
    return document.getElementById("demoX").innerHTML = xxx;
    //break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `innerHTML` every time you go through the loop so when it finishes you only get the last one. You can either use `document.getElementById("demoX").innerHTML += xxx;` or if you want it to cycle through them use `setInterval`. Also, as the above answer states, put it inside the loop

Comment: @ScottMarcus why is that?

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, updating the DOM from within a loop is a big-time performance "no no" as successive changes to the DOM cause the user agent to rebuild the DOM each time.

Instead, build up a string in your loop and then set the final value of the string into your DOM element once the loop is done.

Also, `.innerHTML` is for when you are passing a string that contains HTML to an element's content and that causes that string to be parsed by the HTML parser. If you are not assigning a string that contains HTML, use `.textContent` instead to avoid that extra work.

Now, to your issue, you are using `=` when you should be using `+=` to have each new value concatenated onto the last value. And, you don't need to `return` anything from this function, you only need it to update the element:

```
function GETJSON() {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < jsoDemo.length; i++) {
    result += jsoDemo[i].name;
  }
  document.getElementById("demoX").textContent = result;
}
```